# How to convert unicode strings to bytes array and vice versa on Delphi-2007

Tags: string, delphi, unicode, encoding, delphi-2007

In *Delphi XE7*, we are converting some values from string to bytes and from bytes to string using:

```
MyBytes := TEncoding.Unicode.GetBytes(MyString);
```

and

```
MyString := TEncoding.Unicode.GetString(MyBytes);
```

I would like to write my own functions that results same values on *Delphi-2007*. I'm really not skilled about chars encoding, I suppose I should use `WideString` type in *Delphi-2007* (It's right?)

```
function StringToBytes(AValue : WideString) : TBytes;
begin
   Result := //...
end;

function BytesToString(AValue : TBytes) : WideString;
begin
   Result := //...
end;
```

Could someone help me in writing this two functions?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Does this matter? Let me explain the problem in greater detail.. In order to save several encrypted strings inside database, we are using our own encryption/decryption functions that work on TBytes. Due to this fact, before encrypt-decrypt, we need to convert strings in TBytes. And here comes the problem.. Two different applications should read these strings and should be able to encrypt and decrypt these (App1 has been compiled in Delphi-2007 and app2 has been compiled in XE7).

Comment: Oh my word, now I understand. It's trivial. Just wait a moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since a `WideString` is UTF-16 encoded, and you want a UTF-16 encoded byte array, no conversion is needed. You can perform a direct memory copy like this:

```
function StringToBytes(const Value : WideString): TBytes;
begin
  SetLength(Result, Length(Value)*SizeOf(WideChar));
  if Length(Result) > 0 then
    Move(Value[1], Result[0], Length(Result));
end;    

function BytesToString(const Value: TBytes): WideString;
begin
  SetLength(Result, Length(Value) div SizeOf(WideChar));
  if Length(Result) > 0 then
    Move(Value[0], Result[1], Length(Value));
end;
```

Comment: It doesn't works on Delphi-2007. As an example, the line "ShowMessage(BytesToString(StringToBytes('aaa')));" shows a dialog displaying 'a'. I think it's because SizeOf(Char) is 1 in delphi-2007. It seems to work by replacing Char with WideChar

Comment: Sorry. I misread that comment. It is me that needs to take more care. The answer is correct now. I forgot that Char is AnsiChar on your compiler.